# Connect to internet which uses pppoe dialup over wifi connection [linux]

Tags: linux, networking, wifi

In windows the internet is accessed by first connecting to the wifi using a password and then using the dial up pppoe connection with our username and password. how do i connect internet in linux using this type of connection. I am using debian and the internet is our university lab wifi. any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean your computer (A) connects via wifi to another computer (B) which connects to the internet via some modem and that you would like computer A ? B ? both ? to run Linux ?

Comment: I don't exactly know the setup but we connect to the wifi ap first like usual and then use the broadband dialup to access the internet in windows. We can also connect to the internet using the same broadband dialup if using wired. I know that there is a switch behind the router and our wired connection.

Comment: Please understand that, in order to provide whatever helpful answer to your question, we would need much more precise answers. Since, whatever you would have to achieve on your system (locally) would require the complicity of the administrator of the network your system is connected to, the owner of the contract with your internet provider as well, I suggest you ask this administrator to either upgrade your question or open a new one.

Answer (score 0):

### Current Topology

```
                                              (Wireless Router)
<---------- Broadband Modem <------> Computer A <-------------> Computer B
(Internet)  (PPoE Connection)       (PPoE Dialer)               (Lab Computer)
```

From reading your question, and having worked in an ISP's tech support center, this is your current topology, which were all a little fuzzy on.

### Questions

1. Is `Broadband Modem - (PPoE  Connection)` just a Box with lights, commonly called an [external or Brick Modem - Example](https://www.surfboard.com/products/cable-modems/sb8200/), or is it possible that it's a [combo modem/router - example](https://www.surfboard.com/products/wi-fi-cable-modems/sbg7400ac2/)?
2. If 1 is a combo device, why has your administrator chosen to handle PPoE negotiation in `Computer A - (PPoE Dialer)`?

There are a plethora of ways to make the setup more efficient, but I believe the lab administrator may be sacrificing efficiency in order to monitor the length of time each student is surfing by monitoring the PPoE Dialer software.